# get image from war file after deploying on tomcat

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat

I have an Assets folder with images under webcontent folder in my project. I have deployed the war file on tomcat on AWS Linux . I have used image names in my code as below.

```
Image arrowImg = Image.getInstance("slider.png");
```

This worked in my local system but it's not working after deploying to Tomcat.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ..you can try using relative path.

Comment: my folder structure is webcontent -> Assets

Comment: have tried with "/Assets/image.png" and "Assets/image.png". both didnt work.

Comment: ..relative path means "/usr1/<folder>/<project-name>/Assets/image.png" ..